# only first line of output gets printed to my text file

Tags: python

I have a text file which I read in and then I extract the data I require and try sending it to different new text file, but only the first line gets into the new text file.

```
    import csv
    f = open('C:\\Users\\c\\Documents\\DCX.txt')
    next(f)
    csv_f=csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_f:
        if 'DCX3520E' in row[0] and 'NULL' not in row[6]:
            with open("out.txt","w") as f1:
                dcx = row[0] + " " + row[6]
                aa = dcx[9:]
                print(aa)
                f1.writelines(aa)
```

Comment: That `.writelines()` doesn't look like it's what you really mean either... Think you're really after `.write`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not open the file inside the for loop. This overwrites the file every time.

```
with open("out.txt","w") as f1:
    for row in csv_f:
        if 'DCX3520E' in row[0] and 'NULL' not in row[6]:
            dcx = row[0] + " " + row[6]
            ...
```

Comment: Yes you right, my biggest mistake was I was opening it inside the for loop and also was in "w" mode but should have been in "a"-append mode.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest issue that I can see if that you're opening your file in write-mode within your for loop. Every time you open a file in write mode you empty the file and delete everything that's currently in there.

The two clear solutions are as follows:

1. Make your `with` line the outer-most context
2. Open in append ('a') mode instead.

Since it seems like you're approaching this problem for your first time I'm going to intentionally avoid posting a full solution. I think it's important that you understand what's going on here and try to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `open("out.txt","w")` opens the file in overwrite mode. Here you may want to use `open("out.txt","a")` to append, but only if you have some good reason to reopen the file every time. Beyond that it's best practice to open the file, write to it many times, then close it i.e.

```
with open("out.txt","w") as out_file:
    for row in csv_f:
        if 'DCX3520E' in row[0] and 'NULL' not in row[6]:
            dcx = row[0] + " " + row[6]
            aa = dcx[9:]
            print(aa)
            out_file.writelines(aa)
```